# how to speed up my process

Tags: python, performance, screen-scraping

I wrote a script that will web scrape data for a list of stocks. The scraper has to get the data from 2 separate pages so each stock symbol must scrape 2 different pages. If I run the process on a list that is 1000 items long it will take around 30 minutes to complete. It's not horrible, I can set it and forget it, but I'm wondering if there is a way to speed up the process. Maybe store the data and wait to write it all at the end instead of on each loop? Any other ideas appreciated.

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from progressbar import ProgressBar
import csv

symbols = {'AMBTQ','AABA','AAOI','AAPL','AAWC','ABEC','ABQQ','ACFN','ACIA','ACIW','ACLS'}
pbar = ProgressBar()

with open('industrials.csv', "ab") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(['Symbol','5 Yr EPS','EPS TTM'])
    for s in pbar(symbols):
        try:
            url1 = 'https://research.tdameritrade.com/grid/public/research/stocks/fundamentals?symbol='
            full1 = url1 + s
            response1 = requests.get(full1)
            html1 = response1.content
            soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1)

            for hist_div in soup1.find("div", {"data-module-name": "HistoricGrowthAndShareDetailModule"}):
                EPS5yr = hist_div.find('label').text

        except Exception as e:
            EPS5yr = 'Bad Data'
            pass

        try:
            url2 = 'https://research.tdameritrade.com/grid/public/research/stocks/summary?symbol='
            full2 = url2 + s
            response2 = requests.get(full2)
            html2 = response2.content
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2)

            for div in soup2.find("div", {"data-module-name": "StockSummaryModule"}):
                EPSttm = div.findAll("dd")[11].text

        except Exception as e:
            EPSttm = "Bad data"
            pass

        writer.writerow([s,EPS5yr,EPSttm])
```

Comment: Relevant:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286559/1079354 - you're going to want to have a read at that before proceeding.  Long story short:  **profile your code.**  Find the hot spots.  Identify and isolate them.  *Then* you should be well-equipped to ask a question of us.

Comment: Also, if this code works, Code Review stack exchange would probably be more helpful.

Comment: multithread your requests using the `multiprocessing` module, or make them [async](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) (or both!)